# GitLab upgrade background migration job not completed

Tags: gitlab, upgrade, gitlab-omnibus

Installation: self-managed GitLab Omnibus

Version: 15.11.6

After multiple upgrades from 12.8.1 to 15.11.6 the Background Migration job “NullifyOrphanRunnerIdOnCiBuilds: ci_builds” has failed at some point and it is stuck running at 73.00%. After some time it fails and if I retry to execute that job it remains stuck at 73.00% and fails again.

This is the job running:
[image]

And this is the message showed:
[image]

Do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

After finding no solution because it seems like the command is written using double quotes over an empty string I solved it truncating the ci_build tables and executing the finalize command for than migration:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:background_migrations:finalize[NullifyOrphanRunnerIdOnCiBuilds,ci_builds,id,[]]
```